# How to create an 'external' database managed with an addon?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, color, linked-data

I have a problematic : I create multiple models but I use always the same colors. I created an addon with the colors inside a dictionnary, but when I want to update some colors, add or remove others, I have to search inside of my addon and it takes a lot of time, because i have now a few hundreds of different colors.

So my question is : how can I store these colors into an external file, and just have a panel in my addon to create, remove or update these colors ? I just can't find if I can use multiple python files in my addon, and modify the one I would use as a database...

Tanks by advance !

Comment: I never used the asset browser, but I guess this is a possible use case for it... but I had to watch tutorials on how to use it to give any substantial answer to this question. Maybe you could look out for tutorials to see if this might help you?

Comment: The simplest file format IMO is json. Could you add a little bit of information about your setup ? You store only color data ? I'm a little intrigued by you saying looking up a dictionary takes a lot of time, accessing a python dict should be almost constant time whatever the number of items inside it. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963507/time-complexity-of-accessing-a-python-dict

Comment: I was studying about Json, which seems to be the best solution indeed. I was worried it couldn't be stored inside an addon, does it have to be an external data?

The problem with dictionnaries is that it is stored inside my python script, and i can't modify my script dynamically : i have to search manually the color i want to update, then modify it. When i have to update or upload dozens of colors, it is a bit long... Tha'ts why i'm searching an other way to store theses datas (i store color, color_name and color_id, and i use it in my panels to create materials)